# write custom functions inside generic class based view in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have to write a custom function inside class based view which is like below:

```
class ExampleView(ListCreateAPIView,
                  UpdateAPIView,
                 DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        /.........some code............./

    def random_custom(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        /.........some code............./
```

Here above I have a random custom function which I need to call from the url. Now I am not sure how to do that. If it was a modelviewset, we can do it easily like this:

```
path("example/",users.ExampleView.as_view({"get": "random_custom"}),
     ),
```

I have done it before in ModelVIewset,ie call custom functions like above but I am not sure how to do that is genericviews like above.

**Update**

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if request.method == 'PUT' and kwargs.get('slug'):
        return self.custom_function(request,*args,**kwargs)
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def custom_function(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    print(instance)

    slug = kwargs.get("slug")
    print(slug)
    print(request.data)
```

Here I can see that from dispatch, the custom function is called and I can see the print of instance and slug but when I print(request.data) it says the error below:

**AttributeError: 'ExampleView' object has no attribute 'data'**

I need request.data to perform some logic in the data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting `random_custom()` into `get()` method? It should be executed right after `GET` method is initialised by client.

```
class ExampleView(...):
    ...
    

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.random_custom()
        /.........some code............./

    def random_custom(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        /.........some code............./
```

Answer (score 2):

The code which makes the decision about which method on your APIView-derived class to call is in APIView.dispatch(). You can read the [source here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/efc7c1d664e5909f5f1f4d07a7bb70daef1c396e/rest_framework/views.py#L485).

Here's how it works:

1. Convert the method name (e.g. GET, POST, OPTIONS) to lowercase. Check that the method name is a valid HTTP method. If not, return an error code.
2. Check if the object defines a lowercase version of the method name. If not, return an error code.
3. Use `getattr()` to get that method, and call it.

This means that there are only two ways to redirect the call from get().

1. Define get() and make it call random_custom(), as @NixonSparrow describes.
2. Override the dispatch() method to call something else.

Those are the only two ways to do it.

Comment: Hello @Nick, I have used dispatch as you said but I got the error saying `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`.